# Separate/isolate $scope variable with same name in 2 different controllers that are in use concurently

Tags: angularjs

I have a `$scope.test.name` in both `'test1' controller` and `'test2' controller`.

The backdrop:

- `'test2' controller` is a pop-out page open above `'test1' controller` page

the issue:

- in `'test2' controller`, if i change value of `$scope.test.name`, it will also change value of `$scope.test.name` of controller 1, since both `'test1' controller` and `'test1' controller` are open concurently

Is there a way to isolate or cut off relation of `$scope.test.name` from both controller beside giving a different name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the controller as syntax:

```
<div ng-controller="Test1Ctrl as test1">
  {{ test1.test.name }}
  <div ng-controller="Test2Ctrl as test2">
    {{ test2.test.name }}   
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

that's because of parent child relationship and test2 comes inside test1 so it will reflect the changes but vice-versa it will not work i will recommend you using directive with isolated scope.

you can refer here https://thinkster.io/egghead/understanding-isolate-scope